# jQuery click event doesn't work properly? How should I write?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make a dropdown menu! It should work like this- when the dropdown is expanded, then parent should have a chevron-up icon and when the dropdown is collapsed, in that time parent should have a chevron-down icon. I do the below code, but it doesn't work correctly. Why?

HTML:

```
<li class="property-trig-mobile"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><span>PROPERTY</span>  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down chevron-trig"></i></a>
                    <ul class="ul-dropdown-mobile">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>PROPERTY DETAILS</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><span>FEATUTES</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i><span>SCHEDULE A SHOWING</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-print"></i><span>PRINT FLYER</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i><span>MORTGAGE CALCULATOR</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i><span>WALK SCORE</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i><span>AERIAL VIEW</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span>CENSUS DATA</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i><span>LOCAL SCHOOLS</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i><span>FLOOR PLANS</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><span>DOCUMENTS</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$('.property-trig-mobile a').on('click',function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('chev');
            $('.ul-dropdown-mobile').slideToggle(200);
            $('.chevron-trig').addClass('fa-chevron-up').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');

        });

        $('.property-trig-mobile a.chev').on('click',function(){
            $('.chevron-trig').addClass('fa-chevron-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');

        });
```

Comment: `$('.property-trig-mobile > a')` ??? or `$('.property-trig-mobile a:not(.chev)')` that for first click handler. But if you define `it doesn't work correctly` then would be easier to see what you are expecting

Comment: Exactly what *"doesn't work correctly"*?  Does the drop down show/hide?  Does it add/remove the chevron?  For some reason you've got 2 click handlers that do different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class with rotate and toggle it on click like this:

css:

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.property-trig-mobile a').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('chev');
    $('.ul-dropdown-mobile').slideToggle(200);
    $('.chevron-trig').toggleClass('rotate');

});
```

you can see the code hier: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjXPyz

Answer (score 2):

The click event on `$('.property-trig-mobile a')` works for both, anchor with `.chev` class and without `.chev` class

You should modify your selector like `$('.property-trig-mobile a:not(.chev)')`

code:

```
$('.property-trig-mobile a:not(.chev)').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('chev');
    $('.ul-dropdown-mobile').slideToggle(200);
    $('.chevron-trig').addClass('fa-chevron-up').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');

});

$('.property-trig-mobile a.chev').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('chev');
    $('.chevron-trig').addClass('fa-chevron-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');

});
```